# Entire feature will be installed on local hard drive using PowerShell

Tags: windows-installer

I am trying to install web deploy on windows server using PowerShell. So I have this script.

```
$temp_path = "c:\azuredata\"

$wd_installer_url = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/D/01DC28EA-638C-4A22-A57B-4CEF97755C6C/WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi"

$wd_installer_file = $temp_path + [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName( $wd_installer_url )

$DataStamp = get-date -Format yyyyMMddTHHmmss
$logFile = '{0}-{1}.log' -f $wd_installer_file,$DataStamp

$MSIArguments = @(
    "/i"
    ('"{0}"' -f $wd_installer_file)
    "/qn"
    "/norestart"
    "/L*v"
    $logFile
)
Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $MSIArguments -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

The webdeploy tool is installed. But when I look into it, all the features are not installed.

[image: Add Features]

Modify web deploy tool.

[image: Modify installed Web deploy tool]

Click change

[image: click change]

Select the features.

[image: Select the features]

As you can see all the features are not installed. Now matter how I manipulate the argument list of the powershell command, its not installing it fully. I had to later do this manually. Tried replacing /i with /a. But it did not help.

```
$MSIArguments = @(
    "/i"
    ('"{0}"' -f $wd_installer_file)
    "/qn"
    "/norestart"
    "/L*v"
    $logFile
)
```

[image: Manuall modification of the installation]

I am sure there must be a way for this. My automation workflow is stuck because of this. Any ideas what can be done? Looked [into this document](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html), but no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use ADDLOCAL=ALL? Something like (untested - on mobile):

```
$MSIArguments = @(
    "/i"
    ('"{0}"' -f $wd_installer_file)
    "/qn"
    "/norestart"
    "ADDLOCAL=ALL"
    "/L*v"
    $logFile
)
```

Here is the [ms docs reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/addlocal).